бежать + genitive
In Бюст Тиберия by Brodsky we have:

Я тоже опрометью бежал всего
со мной случившегося и превратился в остров
с развалинами, с цаплями.

I don't know the construction бежать + génitive. I know the constructions бежать из and бежать от (actually I don't really know when  I should use which preposition). Do we have бежать + génitive =  бежать от (or бежать из)?

Бежать + gen. means "to avoid".
It's mentioned on Wiktionary, sense 9.


Я мрачен, дик, людей бегу, // Хотел бы иногда их видеть; // Но я не должен, не могу: // Боюсь друзей возненавидеть. П. А. Плетнев, «Объяснение», 1826 г.
Как бежать своих терзаний в склонах гор? М. А. Кузмин, «Алость злата — блеск фазаний в склонах гор!..», 1908 г.


It's a bookish word. Usually, избегать is used instead.


I know the constructions бежать из and бежать от (actually I don't really know when I should use which preposition)

Бежать из/c and бежать от both mean "to run" (direct sense) or "to run away, flee, escape from" (metaphorical sense).
You use из/c when the object is a place. Its opposite would be бежать в/на, as in "I'm running from Moscow to St. Petersburg" or "I'm fleeing from Moscow to St. Petersburg"


— Тогда объясните мне, почему он не сделал попытки бежать из театра, когда начался переполох? [Вера Белоусова. Второй выстрел (2000)]
Мать его, коммунистка, бежала из Польши с ним и его старшим братом в Россию, отец остался в Польше и погиб. [Людмила Улицкая. Пиковая дама (1995-2000)]
Но вот опять бегут из перевязочной, стряслось что-нибудь... [Николай Амосов. Голоса времен (1999)]


You use от in two cases:

When the object is a place and you use it to define the starting point and the direction you're running away from. Its opposite would be бежать к, as in "I'm running away from Moscow and towards St. Petersburg":


«Задыхаясь, я бежал от станции к дому… [И. Н. Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский (2015)]
Вчера я вышла на крыльцо и вдруг вижу бежит от дома вниз к загородке зверь. [Г. П. Зайцева. Дневник (1982)]



When the object is a person, animal, situation, etc., something that's chasing or haunting you. There is no opposite in this case.


Харар основан лет девятьсот тому назад мусульманскими выходцами из Тигре, бежавшими от религиозных преследований, и смешавшимися с ними арабами. [Н. С. Гумилев. Африканский дневник (1913)]
В эти годы во Владивостоке, куда бежали от революции и войны, население росло. [В. О. Авченко. Фадеев (2017)]




